# The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
class _CreateRoomButton extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  return OutlineButton(
    onPressed: () => print('Create Room'),
     color: Colors.white,
  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blueAccent[100]),
  textColor: Palette.facebookBlue,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Icon(
        Icons.video_call,
        size: 35.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      )
    ],
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
);
}
}
```

I have used an Outline Button in which I wanna set the border color to blueAccent[100]. On trying to do so the following error comes up :

The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.

Also I wanna shift the outline button into the new Outlined Button but I am unable to style that acc to the app.

Comment: `Colors.blueAccent[100]!` try using this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see Colors.blueAccent[100] actually gets a value from map. So if your version of flutter is bellow 2.0 you would get this error since it may return a null value.

Now why did this happen: This is because if you are using flutter 2.2 which is by default null-safe. You will get many errors.

Solution : `Colors.blueAccent[100]!` or `Colors.blueAccent.shade100;`

For OutlinedButton:

```
  OutlinedButton.icon(
    label: Text('MY BUTTON'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
    onPressed: () {
      print('Pressed');
    },
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
     BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
),
  )
```

You can tap into more properties : [From here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html) or you can see this [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/components/buttons/flutter) or this blog [This Blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widgets-buttons-the-whole-picture-5662a3b58b8f)

Answer (score 0):

you have updated flutter sdk i think and using null safety feature. just add ! after color.

```
color: Colors.blueAccent[100]!,
```

> Note : Outlinebutton is deprecated use outlinedbutton instead.

[Flutter Outlinedbutton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html)

Comment: its a null safety feature variables can’t contain null unless you say they can.. https://dart.dev/null-safety#:~:text=When%20you%20opt%20into%20null,into%20edit%2Dtime%20analysis%20errors.